# Cannot execute any command even with root user

Tags: debian, chmod

I accidentally execute this command on my / folder
Chmod -R 600 .
Now my root user have no right to execute anything even chmod
How can i solve it?

Thk.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem , by mounting my disk on another system instance